# Adding ndarray into dataframe and then back to ndarray

Tags: python, dataframe, series, numpy-ndarray

I have a ndarray which looks like this:

```
x
```

[image: data ndarray]

I wanted to add this into an existing dataframe so that I could export it as a csv, and then use that csv in a separate python script, pull out the ndarray and carry out some analysis, mainly so that I don't have one really long python script.

To add it to a dataframe I've done the following:

```
data["StandardisedFeatures"] = x.tolist()
```

[image: dataframe]

This looks ok to me. However, in my next script, when I try to pull out the data and put it back as an array, it doesn't appear the same, it's wrapped in single quotes and treating it as a string:

```
data['StandardisedFeatures'].to_numpy()
```

[image: not an array]

I've tried astype(float) but it doesn't seem to work, can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list objects in a DataFrame have become strings while processing (happens sometimes), you can use `eval` or [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) functions to convert back from string to list, and use `map` to do it for every element.

Here is an example which will give you an idea of how to deal with this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dic = {"a": [1,2,3], "b":[4,5,6], "c": [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [1,2,3]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

print("DataFrame:", df, sep="\n", end="\n\n")

print("Column of list to numpy:", df.c.to_numpy(), sep="\n", end="\n\n")
temp = df.c.astype(str).to_numpy()

print("Since your list objects have somehow become str objects while working with df:", temp, sep="\n", end="\n\n")

print("Magic for what you want:", np.array(list(map(eval, temp))), sep="\n", end="\n\n")
```

Output:

```
DataFrame:
a  b          c
0  1  4  [1, 2, 3]
1  2  5  [4, 5, 6]
2  3  6  [1, 2, 3]

Column of list to numpy:
[list([1, 2, 3]) list([4, 5, 6]) list([1, 2, 3])]

Since your list objects have somehow become str objects while working with df:
['[1, 2, 3]' '[4, 5, 6]' '[1, 2, 3]']

Magic for what you want:
[[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[1 2 3]]
```

Note: I have used `eval` in the example only because more people are familiar with it. You should prefer using `ast.literal_eval` instead whenever you need eval. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) nicely explains why you should do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can save objects of any type in a DataFrame.

You retain their type, but they will be classified as "object" in the `pandas.DataFrame.info()`.

Example: save lists

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(my_list=[[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]))
print(type(df.loc[0, 'my_list']))
# Print: list
```

This is useful if you use your objects directly with `pandas.DataFrame.apply()`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an alternative and simpler way of solving this issue is to use `numpy.save` and `numpy.load` functions. Then you can save the array as a numpy array object and load it again in the next script directly as a numpy array:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
# Save the array in the working directory as "x.npy" (extension is automatically inserted)
np.save("x", x)
# Load "x.npy" as a numpy array
x_loaded = np.load("x.npy")
```